# Better ways of inserting simple HTML into a div using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm always seeming to have to insert HTML into a load of `div`s using jQuery, but I prefer JavaScrip and wonder if anybody has any better ways of doing it. See the typical example below:

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.main-editor-output');
for (let box of boxes) {
  console.log(box);
  $( "<p>Test</p>" ).prependTo(box);
}
```

```css
.main-editor-output {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='parent'>
  <div class="main-editor-output"></div>
  <div class="main-editor-output"></div>
</div>
```

Here I'm just using a simple line of jQuery to insert HTML into the test divs. I could do it using javascript, but that would require too many lines of code. Does anyone have any better ways of doing this?

Thanks for any ideas!

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/GRKGwZP

Comment: Use `document.createElement` and `insertBefore`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `insertAdjacentHTML`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

in your example it would be `box.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p>Test</p>');`

demo:

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.main-editor-output');

for (let box of boxes) {
  console.log(box);
  box.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<p>Test</p>');
}
```

```css
.main-editor-output {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>


<div id='parent'>
  <div class="main-editor-output">
    Existing text
  </div>
  <div class="main-editor-output">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Vanilla JavaScript you can:

- create an item with [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- append it with [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- prepend it with [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

For example, the following code will create two `input`s, assign them an `id` and a `value`, then append the first and prepend the second inside a `div` with `id` *container*:

```js
let container = document.getElementById('container');

let input1 = document.createElement('input');
input1.id = 'input1';
input1.value = 'I am input 1!';
container.appendChild(input1);

let input2 = document.createElement('input');
input2.id = 'input2';
input2.value = 'I am input 2!';
container.insertBefore(input2, input1);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: OP uses `prependTo`, `appendChild` and prepend works differently. You can use `insertBefore`

Comment: @SagarV thanks, I have added this detail to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use **$element.innerHTML**, which is a native JavaScript property of elements.

It works similar to the jQuery element method **$element.html()**.

```
<div id="test">Pre Text</div>
<script> document.querySelector('#test').innerHTML = 'Post Text'; </script>
```

Comment: This will replace whole html content of the div. OP uses prependTo not html

Comment: In the provided example the **main-editor-output** elements do not have sub-elements nor real text content, so using **innerHTML** has basically the same effect like **prependTo** (and is even a better practice).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's exactly what you're looking for, but in any case you can use **document.createElement** to create the child element, and add it to the parent element using the **prepend** method:

```js
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.main-editor-output');
for (let box of boxes) {
  console.log(box);
  let element = document.createElement("p");
  element.append("Test");
  box.prepend(element);
}
```

```css
.main-editor-output {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  min-height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<head>
 
</head>


<div id='parent'>
  <div class="main-editor-output">

  </div>
  <div class="main-editor-output">

  </div>
</div>
```